# Subject Line for Email to CEO

Tags: internship, email

I recently went to a business conference and handed out my resume to a CEO of a large company. I gave him my resume and he gave me his contact info in order to email him for summer internship (I am a college student.)

I am emailing him saying how I enjoyed his presentation, thanking him for talking to me and following up in regards to the internship opportunity.

What would be a professional and effective subject line of my email? I want him to open the email and not dismiss it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not a letter writing service.

Comment: Well, what do *you* want it to say? You want to sound professional, polite, assertive...? What is your goal?

Comment: @DarkCygnus I would like it to sound all of the above, mostly professional. I want him to open the email.

Comment: Why oh why would anyone close this question?!   It's one of the best ones this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subject: Possible summer internship (We met at the XYZ conference)**

That makes it clear why you're emailing and that you've already met (even if he doesn't recognize your email address)

Comment: I would drop the question mark, it would be more assertive that way. other phrasing may be *"Regarding summer internship (We met at XYZ)"*

Comment: I would also only attach your resume and keep the email less than 3 sentences. Something like, *I enjoyed our meeting at the conference. Attached is my resume. Thank you for considering me.*

Comment: very nice subject line!!!!!!!! bravo!

Comment: Dark Swan's comment is also a superb variation.

Comment: @Fattie thanks, and also thanks for the username suggestion :D